# Understanding geometry of quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Let $L$ be a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely, a line, say, the set of $(x,y)$ with $y = x$.  and consider the quotient $\mathbb{R}^2/L$. The equivalence classes, which make up the elements of this quotient space, are exactly the set of ordered pairs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose difference is an element of the line $y = x$. The equivalence class of the point $(a,b)$, assuming $a \neq b$, ends up being the line through $(a,b)$ parallel to the line $y = x$.

This geometry makes sense to me. By simple number-crunching, I can also see that
$$\dim \mathbb{R}^2/L  = \dim \mathbb{R}^2 - \dim L = 2 - 1 = 1.$$
I am trying to understand why, geometrically, it makes intuitive sense for the dimension to be $1$ or why it makes sense to say there is "one degree of freedom." When I sketch the picture, it almost looks like I'm picking a line up and "scaling it" across the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, in which case the only degree of freedom is "vertical distance" of some kind. Is there a better way to think of this?

Comment: the space $\mathbb{R}^2/L$ is just the space of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with slope one, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, that is, you can construct a linear bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2/L$

Comment: It makes sense that there is an isomorphism, but could you explain more about how I would show that (i.e., what the mapping is)?

Comment: by example the map $x\mapsto [(x,0)]$ is an example, where $[\cdot ]$ means "equivalent class"

Comment: It makes sense if we're working with only a one-dimensional axis in the plane, but what if that isn't the case?

Comment: I dont follow what you mean. Note that the elements of $\mathbb{R}^2/L$ have the form $(x,y)+L=(x-y,0)+L$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble seeing this. $(x,y)$ is an arbitrary point of $\mathbb{R}^2/L$, and adding another point of $L$ shouldn't impact equivalence, but after that this equation isn't making sense to me.

Comment: no, $(x,y)$ is an arbitrary point of $\mathbb{R}^2$, not of $\mathbb{R}^2/L$. The corresponding point of $\mathbb{R}^2/L$ is the subset $(x,y)+L$, what is the same set that $(x-y,0)+L$

Comment: Why are they the same, though? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: because $(x,y)+L:=\{(x+z,y+z):z\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Read carefully the definition of a quotient vector space and how it cosets are defined

Answer (score 1):

Since you quotient by a line, it can be convenient to choose your coordinates so that one axis, say the $y$-axis is coincident with $L$.  Then every point has coordinates in this coordinate system and the quotient collapses each point $(x,y) \mapsto x$.  That is, the quotient acts like the linear map $(x,y) \mapsto 1 \cdot x + 0 \cdot y$.  Now look at the nullspace of this map, which is one dimensional and think about the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).